# Pandas accessing rows - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rows

I have this df:

```
Source1   Source2    ID1    ID2
  CH        PAYE      1      2
  CH        PAYE      3      4 
  CH        PAYE      5      6
```

i can access the rows as a range through `df[x:y]`, however whenever i try to access a specific row `df[1]` it comes back with an error.

I need the values of the header and the first row, the header is simple by

`for i in df[:0]:
    print(i)`

although for ;

`for i in df[1]:
    print(i)`

it doesn't give; `(CH,PAYE,1,2)`. Why not?

Comment: use `iloc` to access ordinal row, also it's zero-based `df.iloc[0]`

Comment: You need `for i in df.loc[1]:` for select row with index `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
#changed default index values
df.index = [1,5,7]
print (df)
  Source1 Source2  ID1  ID2
1      CH    PAYE    1    2
5      CH    PAYE    3    4
7      CH    PAYE    5    6
```

For select by `index=1` method [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for i in df.loc[1]:
    print(i)
CH
PAYE
1
2
```

For select by position `1` method [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
for i in df.iloc[1]:
    print(i)
CH
PAYE
3
4
```

Another method [ix will be deprecated](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) in next vrsion of pandas.

Also check:

- [Selection by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)
- [Selection by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)